# Extracting information from multiple websites using scrapy and CSS Selectow

Tags: python, scrapy

I am fetching information from multiple websites for the same I need to select the div class by a regex. I am using scrapy and the css selector.
I am able to do so for a single website with 
*response.css("div[class = 'user-review-content']").extract_first()*

The regex I am trying to use is '.*review.*|.*comment.*'

How can I integrate CSS in it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like that, instead, check in your callback function the URL of domain, and then write code for it

```
if "website1.com" in response.url:
    name_selector = "div.name"
elif "website2.com" in response.url:
    name_selector = "span.name"

item = {}

item = response.css(name_selector).extract_first()
```

I have been doing this in my large scale projects for a long time.